# How to solve this inequality involving trig functions: $\frac{\sin B + \sin C}{2}\leq \sin\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right)$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, triangles, angle

[Source - Larsen 1.3.12](http://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ekrubin/oldcourses/12.194/ps1.pdf)

#### Problem:

> Prove using $y=\sin(x)$ graph, for $A,B,C$ as angles of triangle, that:
>
> $$\frac{\sin B + \sin C}{2}\leq \sin\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right)$$

#### Attempt:

*(without graph)*

Using sum-to-product formula, $\sin B+\sin C=2\sin(\frac{B+C}{2})\cos(\frac{B-C}{2})$

So,

$$\frac{\sin B + \sin C}{2}=\sin(\frac{B+C}{2})\cos(\frac{B-C}{2})$$
$$=\sin(\frac{180-A}{2})\cos(\frac{B-C}{2})$$
$$=\cos(\frac{A}{2})\cos(\frac{B-C}{2})$$
$$=\frac{\cos(\frac{A+B-C}{2})+\cos(\frac{A-B+C}{2})}{2}$$
$$=\frac{\cos(\frac{180-2C}{2})+\cos(\frac{180-2B}{2})}{2}$$
$$=\frac{\sin C+\sin B}{2}$$

And I think I arrived where I had begun.

**Question:**

How to solve this inequality? *(without graph)*

Comment: use $cos\left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right) \le 1$

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma Thanks! I posted an answer based on your observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Ekaveera's hint, right at the first step we have:

$$\frac{\sin B + \sin C}{2}=\sin(\frac{B+C}{2})\cos(\frac{B-C}{2})$$

Now, since $-1<\cos A<1$ for any $0<A<180$, we have:

$$\frac{\sin B + \sin C}{2} \leq \sin(\frac{B+C}{2})$$

Answer (score 1):

Another proof, based on properties of the sine function is that it is true because, on $[0,\pi]$,  sine  is a *concave* function, since $\;(\sin)''(x)=-\sin x\le 0$ on this interval.

Comment: A consequence of [Jensen's inequality](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Jensen's_Inequality).

Comment: I haven't learnt about concave functions. I think I will check this out when I learn about them :)